# PEP8 hanging indent specification

Tags: python, pep8

PEP 8 regarding hanging indent:

> When using a hanging indent the following considerations should be applied; there should be no arguments on the first line and further indentation should be used to clearly distinguish itself as a continuation line.

Is there any explicit official documentation about about "sub-arguments"? For example:

```
some_method(argument_one, argument_two, argument_three=[
    'parameter_one',
    'parameter_two',
    'parameter_three',
    ])
```

As opposed to:

```
some_method(
    argument_one,
    argument_two,
    argument_three=[
        'parameter_one',
        'parameter_two',
        'parameter_three',
        ]
    )
```

Comment: The best thing to do is strive for readability. Usually that means to follow guidelines, but sometimes not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From PEP 8's "Other Recommendations" section:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.

With this recommendation in mind, your 2nd example is probably more in line with the PEP 8 style guide, as it avoids compounding the method invocation and list construction on the same line. The 2nd example reads a little easier too.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this question is years old, but I wanted to share my thoughts and the approach that has worked for me, especially because I am legally blind. (I specifically aim for shallow nesting and to keep my function calls as simple and readable as possible.)

In order to avoid potentially tricky readability situations like this, I will actually pre-define the list (or any item that creates a complex, messy function call) as a variable, clearly named with some form of indication that it is temporary:

```
# Build temp argument to avoid messy function call.
arg3_tmp = [
    'parameter1',
    'parameter2',
    'parameter3',
]
some_method(argument1, argument2, arg3_tmp)
```